# How to set a constraint where two optimization variables are not non-zero at the same time?

Tags: constraints, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I have optimization variables `x1` and `x2`. Each have different costs in the objective. I need a constraint to make `x1 = 0` when `x2 > 0` and `x2 = 0` when `x2 > 0`. It's also okay to have `x1 = x2 = 0`. The constraint itself would be `[x1 * x2 == 0]` but this is not convex. How can I get around this?

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-convex constraint. It is sometimes called a complementarity constraint. Indeed

```
x1*x2 = 0
```

is one way. Another approach is to use binary variables:

```
x1 ≤ U ⋅ δ 
x2 ≤ U ⋅ (1-δ)
δ ∈ {0,1}
```

where U is an upper bound on x1 and x2. This is now linear.

Some other, maybe more exotic, approaches include using a complementarity solver, using indicator constraints or using SOS1 variables.